# How to replace white background color with transparent of an image in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, background-image, background-color

I have an image in `.jpg format` with `white background color`. I want to remove the white background color to transparent in `Imagemagick`. I tried many ways but still the white background can not be removed. Can some one help me to solve this.

Comment: What did you try? You may have to convert it to "indexed color" mode (e.g. PNG) first. Regardless of how you do it, you can expect artifacts to appear at the boundary between image and transparent.

Comment: Transparent to white: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730399/making-white-background-transparent-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First, you need to convert the image format from `.jpg` to `.png` format, because JPEG does not support transparency. Then use this command:

`convert image1.png -fuzz 20% -transparent white result.png`

The `-fuzz` option allows the specified percentage deviation from the pure white colour to be converted to transparent as well. This is useful, for example, when your image contains noise or subtle gradients.

Comment: What was wrong with my answer? (You didn't tell in your question that you required some degree of fuzziness, nor did you provide a sample file -- so it was impossible to guess...)

Comment: It's not necessary to convert the files *first* from JPEG to PNG, and only *then* convert white to transparent. My command does it all in *one* go.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I understand he could have helped you improve your answer instead of answering his own; but without the `-fuzz 20%` it did not work here; I think your answer could be improved with the fuzz option btw, I see absolutely no problem on doing that; also his answer is not completely right as I could go straight from a jpg to a png result; and at last, both answers brings a serious problem; the contour background color (that is black here) becomes transparent; but also all black inside the actual image becomes transparent too; what actually messed my image... :>

Answer (score 83):

You cannot have transparent background colors in your JPEGs. The JPEG file format doesn't support transparency.

If you need transparent background, you need to convert the JPEG to

- either PNG (high quality, filesize possibly larger than JPEG)
- or GIF (in case you can tolerate low quality and a range of maximally 255 colors).

**Example command:**

```
convert  your.jpg  -transparent white  your.png
```

Comment: i must have read your post, and not your actual command; thought you were suggesting "manually converting" sorry for the mix-up, I voted up your answer. I'm not very familiar with the syntax but i am with its capabilities.

Comment: This works great...but if you have any white in the image then it'll convert that to be transparent as well. You could work around that by manually filling in the background to another color then making that color transparent. I don't think this is what OP is looking for but I'll probably use a non-CLI tool like https://www.remove.bg

Answer (score 14):

I just found a very neat thing!

```
magicwand 1,1 -t 20 -f image -r outside -m overlay -o 0 image.jpg imgOutput.png
```

It is a Fred Weinhaus bash script that can be downloaded from [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/magicwand/) (for non commercial use only). Also there has about 250 scripts!! and this one is amazing! it did exactly the trick, to remove all background while keeping the inner image dots untouched!

At his page, there are several images as examples so you pick what you need to put on the command line!

The initial position `1,1` is a general guesser saying all the contour is background.

Pay attention that the output must be ".png"

Answer (score 5):

Get the background automatically and remove it :

```
bg=$(convert input.png -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:)
convert input.png -fuzz 20% -transparent "$bg" output.png
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution without magicwand (replace `magick` by `convert` for im < 7.0):

```
magick img.png -fuzz 20% -fill none -draw "alpha 1x1 floodfill" result.png
```

Comment: at ubuntu imagemagick v8:6.7.7.10 - error `convert.im6: non-conforming drawing primitive definition 'alpha' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3158.`, any idea?

Comment: Here is the right command for imagemagick 6: 

convert "./input.jpg"  -fill none -draw 'color 1,1 floodfill' output.png